# Using Bash Builtin: Complete (Help!)

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Can't seem to find a `man complete` page, so was hoping folks could help explain the options in the complete command (from `complete --help`):

```
complete: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [name ...]
Specify how arguments are to be completed by Readline.

For each NAME, specify how arguments are to be completed.  If no options
are supplied, existing completion specifications are printed in a way that
allows them to be reused as input.

Options:
  -p        print existing completion specifications in a reusable format
  -r        remove a completion specification for each NAME, or, if no
            NAMEs are supplied, all completion specifications
  -D        apply the completions and actions as the default for commands
            without any specific completion defined
  -E        apply the completions and actions to "empty" commands --
            completion attempted on a blank line

When completion is attempted, the actions are applied in the order the
uppercase-letter options are listed above.  The -D option takes
precedence over -E.
```

I am trying to have BOTH the commands for a `bash` script as option 1 to complete and (ideally when appropriate) valid files and/or directories next.  Is this possible using `complete` or do I need a different approach?

Right now, I have this:

`complete -W "mount unmount" phone`

...for a script called `phone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your request *"help explain the options in the complete command"*:

It is a longer story to tell all details, hence find a list of hopefully useful documentation references at the end of this post.

About your specific use case to complete `$1` as command and `$2` as files, I have added a small example in the next section.

### Example

**Write a completion function** that handles positional differences:

```
# completion function to differentiate type of completion by argument type
_complete_phone () {
  case ${#COMP_WORDS[@]} in
    1) # 1st position is the `phone` command itself
       return;;
    2) # 2nd position are sub-commands, so we use `-W` for word completion
       words="mount unmount"
       COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$words" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"))
       ;;
    *) # other arguments filter files, either
       # any files using option `-f`
       #COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"))
       # and for specific files (i.e. pattern `*.phone`), use words again
       COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(ls *.phone 2>/dev/null)" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"))
       ;;
  esac
}
```

Then **activate completion by function** activated with the `-F` argument, using your completion function name:

```
# complete using your function 
complete -F _complete_phone phone
```

And finally, try (for reproducibility an arbitrary program `phone` and 'relevant' files have to be created):

```
# try
phone () { echo "hello, phone program will $@"; }
touch {my,your}.phone
phone m\tab \tab \tab
```

---

### Documentation

**Bash Reference Manual**

An excellent go-to resource of documentation when you want more details about `bash`.

Specific for bash completion, have a look into chapters

- **8.4** Bindable Readline Commands

  - **8.4.6** [Letting Readline Type For You](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html)
- **8.7** [Programmable Completion Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html)
- **8.8** [A Programmable Completion Example](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/A-Programmable-Completion-Example.html)

> Source: [www.gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org)

**Bash Manual**

Run `man bash` and go to sections:

- `READLINE`

  - `Readline Variables` explaining how to `set` variables related to completion. For example `set completion-ignore-case on` to "perform filename matching and completion in case insensitive fashion".
  - `Completing` default bash completion.
  - `Programmable Completion` explaining the process of completion, and relevant elements such as methods `compgen`, variables `COMP_WORDS`, etc. you find in the example above.
- `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS`

  - `compgen` to generate completion matches.
  - `complete` to specify how to complete. Also describes all options, such as `-W`, `-F`, `-o`, etc.
  - `compopt` to set other completion options.

> Source: GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)